# Is there a way to convert FLOPS to bit operation per second

Tags: arithmetic, floating-point, performance, high-performance-computing

My problem is the following: I have $N$ inner products to compute in parallel every second.
Each of the vectors in those inner product is composed of $7$ bits.

I want to know for which $N$ it starts to become computationally intensive to do that, let's say that a supercomputer would have struggle to follow it.

I know that there is the FLOPS unit which tell me how many floating point operation I can do per second. But here those are bit operation per second that I need to know, and I don't have access to this information.

Is there a way to find the number I am looking for ? I am interested by some rough idea.

For instance, a single precision float is composed of number of $32$ bits. Can I just take the FLOPS and multiply it by $32$ to have some rough idea of what I am looking for ?

Comment: Not quite clear what you mean: You have vectors of length seven, and each vector element is either 0 or 1?

Comment: @gnasher729 exactly. And I need to make a scalar product between two such vectors. My question is for how many of those scalar product done per second it will start to become "heavy" in term of processing. I think the answer can be done by "converting" FLOPS in Bit Operation Per Second but I am not sure.

Comment: It would be great if a machine that could do n 64-bit floating point computations per second could do 64n 1-bit computations per second, but that's not typically how things scale. The machine will have a word size or unit of work it operates at, and data smaller than that word size will still take one full word worth of iteration time to be processed. You may be able to pack multiple pieces of data into one word to get multiple results at once, then combine those results to get your final answer, as long as the packing/combining isn't more work than just doing the calcs individually.

Comment: @DMGregory would you agree with the following: A dedicated machine for floating point operations would in the worst case operate as fast for bit operations than for float ones. But it is likely that it is possible to design a dedicated bit-operaion machine that would work faster than the FLOPS one. It is just a matter of design: if we can do K FLOPS technically it is likely that we could do much more BIT OPERATION PER SECOND if we designed appropriately the object.

Comment: How quickly a custom-designed ASIC could solve your problem might be a question for the [Electronics Engineering StackExchange](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/search?q=asic).